# text to image conversion

Tags: android

i just succeeded in calling a line of text from a text file in th sdcard and got it to display the text out on the application via textview,

is there anyway where i could read the characters from the text and then get it to display a image below the character

like an text to image conversion right below each line of text

the text are short and simple words

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can create a bitmap manually and draw text into it using the Paint and Canvas classes

Something like this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(30, 30, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Paint paint = new Paint();
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
canvas.drawText("TEXT", 0, 0, paint);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, how about if i want to link to an existing picture like A would map to an apple picture, B to bird picture

Comment: I've never tried it, but I can't see why you can't draw into an existing Bitmap. You can modify the code above to use your existing Bitmap as the argument for the Canvas constructor