# Convert text to image and then retrieve the same

Tags: android

In my app I wanted to enter a text in edit-text , then convert it as an image and then retrieve the same image to the image view .Can you say how to do this or please mention a tutorial for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860391/text-to-image-conversion).  Basicaly you make a bitmap, and draw your text to it with a paint.  Then just put the bitmap into your image view.